# Android Horizontal determinate ProgressBar is not running

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to change from indeterminate to determinate horizontal progress bar but determinte progress bar doesn't work where indeterminate works so fine.

Determinate one appears but no motion.
please help me .

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/check"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     <ProgressBar  
     android:id="@+id/my_progressBar"
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="10"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**And i added the following in MainActivity.java:**

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.my_progressBar);  
progressBar.setProgress(20);
```

Comment: The progress start at 20 and does not increase?

Comment: @Diekrul    yes it stays there and doesn't increases

Answer (score 1):

I think the progressBar dont increse because you dont increment de progress. If you set setProgress to 20, the bar will remain at 20.

You have to progressively increase the setProgress if you want to see motion.

I hope its helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private int progressStatus = 10;        
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {

                   while (progressStatus < 100) {

                           progressStatus += 5;

                           // Update the progress bar and display the
                           //current value in the text view
                           handler.post(new Runnable() {
                               public void run() {
                                   progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());

                               }
                           });
                           try {
                               // Sleep for 300 milliseconds.
                               //Just to display the progress slowly
                               Thread.sleep(300);
                           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }


               }

           }
       }).start();
```